# Comparison of Models for Margin and Win Prediction

Tags: regression, logistic, linear

I recently created two models for predicting the outcomes of matches for a particular sport, one is a linear regression model that predicts the margin of the match, and the other is a logistic regression model for predicting the probability of the outcome of the match. I noticed that occasionally the logistic model will predict team A to win (e.g. 57% chance), and the linear model will predict a margin in favour of the opposing team (say, team B wins by 1 goal) for the same match. Both models are trained on the same data and features. I'm curious to know why, and how, this difference between the two models arises. Thanks!

Comment: Because they are different models that work differently (different assumptions - different methods), so you cannot expect them to return similar results, in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case I'm not missing anything from your explanation (some data and details of the model would be useful, though), I guess the reason lies in the different error functions the two models use. In the linear model, you are minimizing the squared difference between the observed and the predicted value:

$$
\sum_i (y_i - \beta \textbf{x}_i - \beta_0)^2,
$$

while in the logistic model you are minimizing:

$$
-\sum_i \left( y_i \log p_i  + (1-y_i) \log (1-p_i) \right).
$$

The other way of looking at it is to say that you have an information loss in the logistic model. It doesn't care by which margin a team has won. If the prediction matches the true outcome, the error will likely be low. In the linear model, on the other hand, if you predict a win by a margin of 1, but the true win was by 100, this will cause a big error.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. Do you think a good metric for expressing this discrepancy between these two models would be to compare the accuracy of match outcome (win/loss) using both the linear and logistic models?

Comment: You can do that. Without the data I can only guess, but my guess is that the linear model will be more accurate.

Comment: Interesting that you would guess that. So, if I want to determine a probability of winning using the linear regression model, am I safe to assume the distribution is normal about my model and calculate the standard deviation in order to measure the probability of winning (i.e. margin greater than zero)